# How to load test specific flow on a website?

Tags: performance, web-services, browser, simulation, load-testing

I used some load testing tools like siege, apache jmeter, httperf which are really useful and suit a lot of cases.

However now I need to benchmark a product sale process that consists of several pages including:

- froms that should be filled with random data and submitted
- cookies / sessions
- concurrent requests
- invalid form data
- ajax requests (form data validation)

In short I would like to simulate a lot of users concurrently buying a product on a webshop (its a so called guest-checkout, so no registration etc is needed)

Right now I am trying to write something in php/curl, specific to the website, but I thought there must be some tools available that I can use. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

I do not need requests from different ip addresses, because the resources expensive stuff happenes all on the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our product, [Web Performance Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/load-tester.html), will do everything you mentioned. Filling out and submitting forms is easy and you can generate random sets of data to fill them with, if needed. It handles cookies automatically (unique for each user) and can simulate any number of requests concurrently - by default it will use the same number as the browser you recorded with. Submitting invalid form data is no different than valid data, you simply put invalid data into the set that feeds the form. You can add validators to check for the success/failure of any request or page. It can handle AJAX requests, though this sometimes requires a few extra configuration steps. The quickest way to get an overview of the product is to watch the first two of these [videos](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/demo/).

Answer (score 1):

Jmeter allows you to script journeys along the lines you describe, and create random values for things like forms. It's got a fairly steep learning curve - but it's got to be better than writing things from scratch!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio WebPerformanceTest and LoadTest will do what you want.  You can create a single data driven test (where you pre-create a bunch of test data), or a single test that uses a plugin that on the fly can generate random data.  This requires licenses for Visual Studio Ultimate or Team Server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out our Fiddler add-on [StresStimulus](http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com/). It does what you described without scripting: records navigation scenario in browser or Fiddler, replays it with configurable load, automatically supports cookie / session correlation for multi-users, monitors in real time and reports errors and timeouts. To generate random data, use the free service [www.generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com) and databind the csv files to web form fields in StresStimulus. For more complex load tests, or if AJAX pages break, Fiddler .NET scripting is available. Up to 100 VUs per machine are free. For more VUs, look at low-cost weekly / monthly subscriptions.